# Plotting ggridges point shapes / colors by variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, ggridges

There probably is an obvious solution to this, but I'm a bit naive with plotting. I'd like to have `point_shape` and `point_fill` defined manually to indicate e.g. gender groups. How would I go about doing this?

In other words, I'd like to see e.g. green squares for females and blue triangles for non-females (as an arbitrary example). (A commenter mentioned that there are no points on the plot, but there are when using the current development version of ggridges.)

```
# Simulate data:
df <- data.frame(female = factor(sample(0:1, size = 500, replace = TRUE)),
                 intervention = factor(sample(0:1, size = 500, replace = TRUE))) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(value = ifelse(female == "1", runif(n = 500, min = 0, max = 100), 
                               rnorm(n = 500, mean = 50, sd = 20)))

# Draw plot:
df %>% 
  ggplot2::ggplot(aes(y = intervention)) +
  ggridges::geom_density_ridges2(aes(x = value, 
                                     colour = "black", 
                                     fill = female),
                                 scale = .7,
                                 alpha = 0.6, 
                                 size = 0.25,
                                 jittered_points = TRUE, 
                                 point_shape = 21,
                                 point_size = 0.85,
                                 point_fill = "black")
```

[image: here]

Comment: There are no points in this plot at all. What points are you trying to draw? Are you trying to draw each observation? What y value do you want to use for each x-value?

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand the part about no points? Added the plot I'm getting with the code, which shows each x-axis observation jittered on y-axis, bounded by the density curve.

Comment: Ok, so the problem was that I forgot I was using the non-CRAN version of the package. Points come with the developmental version. Thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package author here. What's going on is the following: In the general case, you want to be able to style point color, size, etc. independently from line color, size, etc. However, standard ggplot can't do this. It has only one `color` aesthetic, for example, that is applied to all points and lines.

To work around this issue I created new aesthetics `point_color`, `point_size`, `point_shape`, etc. that apply specifically to points. You can map data onto them as you normally would. However, ggplot then doesn't have a way to create scales for them, and therefore I created `scale_discrete_manual()` (and a few other scales) that you can use to define appropriate scales.

Putting all of this together, you arrive at something like this:

```
# Draw plot:
df %>% 
  ggplot2::ggplot(aes(y = intervention)) +
  ggridges::geom_density_ridges2(aes(x = value, 
                                     point_color = female,
                                     point_fill = female,
                                     point_shape = female,
                                     fill = female),
                                 scale = .7,
                                 alpha = 0.6, 
                                 size = 0.25,
                                 jittered_points = TRUE, 
                                 point_size = 0.85) +
  ggplot2::scale_fill_manual(values = c("#A0FFA0", "#A0A0FF")) +
  ggridges::scale_discrete_manual(aesthetics = "point_color", values = c("#00BF00", "#0000BF")) +
  ggridges::scale_discrete_manual(aesthetics = "point_fill", values = c("#80FF80", "#8080FF")) +
  ggridges::scale_discrete_manual(aesthetics = "point_shape", values = c(22, 24))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

We cannot see the points with the `ggridges` version currently available on CRAN.

You are using options that are available only from the development version of
`ggridges` available on github :

```r
library(tidyverse)
# Simulate data:
df <- data.frame(female = factor(sample(0:1, size = 500, replace = TRUE)),
                 intervention = factor(sample(0:1, size = 500, replace = TRUE))) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(value = ifelse(female == "1", runif(n = 500, min = 0, max = 100), 
                                 rnorm(n = 500, mean = 50, sd = 20)))

# devtools::install_github("clauswilke/ggridges")
library(ggridges)

ggplot(df, aes(y = intervention)) +
    geom_density_ridges2(aes(x = value, fill = female),
                         scale = .7,
                         alpha = 0.6, 
                         size = 0.25,
                         jittered_points = TRUE, 
                         point_shape = 21,
                         point_size = 0.85,
                         point_fill = "black") 
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 8.06
```

[image]

It seems impossible to map the aesthetics of the points to any variables. They need to be
fixed values. I tried to specify manually the shapes but it does not work :

```r
ggplot(df, aes(y = intervention)) +
    geom_density_ridges2(aes(x = value, fill = female),
                                   scale = .7,
                                   alpha = 0.6, 
                                   size = 0.25,
                                   jittered_points = TRUE, 
                                   point_shape = c(21,22)[df$female],
                                   point_size = 0.85,
                                   point_fill = "black") 
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 8.06
#> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2548): size, scale, alpha, point_shape, point_size, point_fill
```

The best I can do is this not very nice plot :

```r
ggplot(df , aes(y = intervention)) +
    geom_density_ridges2(aes(x = value, fill = female),
                         scale = .7,
                         alpha = 0.6, 
                         size = 0.25) +
    geom_point(aes(x = value, shape = female), 
               position = position_jitter(height = 0.2, width = 0))
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 8.06
```

[image]

You could probably post an issue/feature request on [github](https://github.com/clauswilke/ggridges/issues)

Created on 2018-04-01 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: No feature request needed. The feature exists already, it's just not documented yet.